# Python 3.5 Fast Food Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I am writing a simple program in Python. But I can't figure why it is not storing a value for Hcount, Scount, and Fcount. Also, it is not displaying the tax correctly. Any help would be appreciated

```
while True:

print("MacDoogle's:")
print("1. Hamburger = $1.50")
print("2. Soda      = $1.15")
print("3. Fries     = $1.25")
print("4. Complete Order")


choice = int(input('Make a selection: '))
while choice < 1 or choice > 4:
    choice = int(input('Enter a valid selection: '))

Hcount =0
Scount =0
Fcount =0 

if choice > 0 and choice <4:

    if choice == 1:
        amount1=int(input("Enter number of Hamburgers: "))
        Hcount += amount1

    elif choice == 2:
        amount2=int(input("Enter number of Sodas: "))
        Scount += amount2

    elif choice == 3:
        amount3=int(input("Enter number of Fries: "))
        Fcount += amount3

if choice == 4:
    sub=int((Hcount * 1.50) + (Scount * 1.15) + (Fcount * 1.25))
    tax=int(sub * 0.09)
    total=int(sub + tax)
    print('Number of Hamburgers:', format(Hcount, '3.0f'))
    print('Number of Sodas:', format(Scount, '3.0f'))
    print('Number of Fries:', format(Fcount, '3.0f'))
    print('Subtotal:', format(sub, '3.2f'))
    print('Tax:', format(tax, '3.2f'))
    print('Total:', format(total, '3.2f'))
    break
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. This is not valid Python code.

Comment: Also your variables should not start with capitalised letters. `Hcount` should be `h_count` or `hcount`

Comment: You also have a bunch of extremely redundant `if`s.

Comment: @AK47. Good point, but to be fair, that is unlikely to be the cause of the code failing.

Comment: Just general coding tips for the newcomer. @Skyla are you running options 1, 2 and 3 before running option 4? Otherwise the variables will not be set

Comment: Also every time your while loop runs, your variables are reset to 0. Consider moving them outside your while loop

Comment: @AK47 I moved the variables outside the while loop, but I still can't get it to calculate tax correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is not https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ however I'm a bit bored and want to help you

1. Indent your code correctly - there should be 4 spaces of indentantion following every `if`, `elif` or `while` statement
2. Move your counter variables outside your `while` loop
3. Change your variables to have lowercase names instead of capitalising the first letter
4. `if choice > 0 and choice < 4` can be re-written as `0 < choice < 4`
5. Your `if choice > 0 and choice < 4` is redundant. You can remove this
6. Your inner `while` loop is redunant - you don't need this at all
7. You can reuse the same variable name in your if statements, no need to create `amount0`, `amount1` and `amount2`
8. When calculating your subtotal and tax amount, you shouldn't be casting the values to `int()` - this removes the decimal place from your number hence the reason your tax is never calculated.
9. When formatting a string you can use `'Subtotal: {:0.2f}'.format(sub)` if you want to format it to 2 decimal places

   ```
   hcount = 0
   scount = 0
   fcount = 0

   while True:
       print("MacDoogle's:")
       print("1. Hamburger = $1.50")
       print("2. Soda      = $1.15")
       print("3. Fries     = $1.25")
       print("4. Complete Order")

       choice = int(input('Make a selection: '))

       if choice == 1:
           amount = int(input("Enter number of Hamburgers: "))
           hcount += amount
       elif choice == 2:
           amount = int(input("Enter number of Sodas: "))
           scount += amount
       elif choice == 3:
           amount = int(input("Enter number of Fries: "))
           fcount += amount
       elif choice == 4:
           sub = (hcount * 1.50) + (scount * 1.15) + (fcount * 1.25)
           tax = sub * 0.09
           total = sub + tax

           print('Number of Hamburgers: {0}'.format(hcount))
           print('Number of Sodas: {0}'.format(scount))
           print('Number of Fries: {0}'.format(fcount))
           print('Subtotal: {:0.2f}'.format(sub))
           print('Tax: {:0.2f}'.format(tax))
           print('Total: {:0.2f}'.format(total))
           break
   ```

Answer (score 0):

That is because Hcount,Scount,Fcount is assigned to 0 everytime the loop iterates. Put `Hcount =0
Scount =0
Fcount =0`
 in front of the while loop and it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This cast to `int` throws away the stuff to the right of the decimal.  Consider storing everything in cents to begin with by multiplying by `100`

```
    sub_in_cents = (hcount * 150) + (scount * 115) + (fcount * 125)
    tax_in_cents = int(sub * 0.09)
    total_in_cents = sub_in_cents + tax_in_cents
    total_in_dollars = total_in_cents*1./100
```